# Please help me identify discourse deixis

Tags: discourse, anaphora, deixis

I am doing my linguistic analysis report but got stuck with finding discourse deixis. In this conversation:

"A: And then because of the difficulties of getting
public transport, if you're working after 11 o'clock we drive you home.
B: Oh, that's good to know."

Is "that" here discourse deixis or just an anaphoric reference?

Comment: Well, what does "that" refer to? A previously referred to individual, or a piece of the preceding utterance?

Comment: I find it so confusing.

Comment: a piece of preceding utterance seems to be what "that" refers to, in my opinion. So the answer for the usage of "that" would be discourse deixis, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would suggest.

Comment: Usually a discourse deixis refers to a proposition (e.g. an information or an argument), whereas anaphora refers to a person or (concrete or abstract) object and is always coreferential with a noun phrase, its so-called antecedent (e.g. "John ... he", "a book" ... "this").

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm really appreciated your help.